# Icon not displaying in notification: white square shown instead and display it using mipmap launcher

Tags: java, android

// 3. Create and send a notification
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)

```
            .setContentTitle("Geofence Monitor")

            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(bigText))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {


        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    } else {
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this) .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }

}
```

}

My question is when i run the app the app on device is supports the mipmap launcher but in loolipop and above devicesis not displaying the the white color and i want to display the same mipmap launcher in lolipop and above devices.
Thanks and help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain appropriate sizes for different drawable folder.

Try these suggested sizes: 
24 × 24 area in 32 × 32 (mdpi)
36 × 36 area in 48 × 48 (hdpi)
48 × 48 area in 64 × 64 (xhdpi)
72 × 72 area in 96 × 96 (xxhdpi)
96 × 96 area in 128 × 128 (xxxhdpi)

and try following these guidelines [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html)